# My function is exceeding the maximum time on google apps script, how i can i change it?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've wrote a function which basically copies rows containing a certain element in one cell. If i run the programm, it is very slow and exceeds the maximum execution time of a script(6 min).

```
function myFunctionMax() {
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var infosheets = sss.getSheetByName("Combined Data");
  var sheeta = sss.getSheetByName("Creator: Max");
  var numbersheet = sss.getSheetByName("Numbers");
    
  sheeta.getRange('A2:T3000').clear();

  const numbers = numbersheet.getRange("C12").getValue();
  Logger.log(numbers);

  var count = 2;
  for(var j=2; j<(numbers + 2) ; j++) {
    if(infosheets.getRange("S" + j ).getValue() == "Max") {
      for(var o=1; o<21;o++){
        sheeta.getRange(count,o).setValue(infosheets.getRange(j,o).getValue())      
      }
      count++;
    }
  }
}
```

Any solution, how i can code it, so it will not exceed the maximum time?

I've tried
`//infosheets.getRange("A" + j + ":T" + j).copyTo(sheeta.getRange('A' + (count) + ':T' + (count) ));`
without the for-loop(var o), but this didnt work for me, through my spreadsheet (Combine Data) is just a reference sheet containing information like "Table1!A3" for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading some other questions on this platform, i've found a different problem but with a solution, that worked out for me! Here is the code!

```
var count = 2;
for(var j=2; j<(numbers + 2) ; j++) {
  if(infosheets.getRange("S" + j ).getValue() == "Max") {
    sheeta.getRange(count,1,1,20).setValues(infosheets.getRange(j,1,1,20).getValues())
    count++;
  }
}
```